# How can I create meta tag with the AntiForgeryToken in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to use ASP.NET NVC to write an application.

I like to add `Meta` tag in my page head that contains the `AntiForgeryToken`. I want to be able to read it via `jQuery` without having to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to the forms that are submitted manually.

I know that `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` will generate a hidden input field, but I need to add a meta tag nstead.

How can I do this without changing the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`?

Comment: first question would be...why would you want to do that

Comment: for easier access. Convenient

Comment: if in order to do that you need to read the old token from the cookie, pass it to the generator. Then get two new tokens one to insert into the meta tag another which you need to write to the return cookie header. And then you need to manually check it by calling a method. Do you still want to do it? I could provide an answer if you still wish to

Comment: There isn't an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to have your CSRF token in a meta tag, try doing the following:

Inside your `_Layout.cshtml` file:

```c#
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Csrf
@functions
{
  public string GetCsrfToken()
  {
    return Csrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
  }
}
```

And then inside your `head` tag, place the following `meta` tag like so:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" content="@GetCsrfToken()" csrf-param="_csrf_token" method-param="_method" name="csrf-token">
```

Comment: corrections:  function directive missing trailing letter s